# How to add elements to a pointer array?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand pointers in C++ by writing some examples. I tried creating a pointer array and when I was trying to add integers to it does not work properly. I want to add integers from 0 to 9 to pointer array and print it.

```
int *array;
array = new int[10];

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
   *array[i] = i;
   cout<<*array<<endl;

}
```

Comment: `array` is used without initialization. The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: You allocate storage for `pInt`, but none for `array` and then try to assign values to `array`. Use `pInt` instead.

Comment: @NickyC.: Is there anything wrong with my solution?

Comment: @NickyC.: Somebody is downvoting my solution questions randomly...... -_-

Comment: @coderredoc Why do you name me?

Comment: @NickyC.: Just mentioned...seeing your comment. The rule is to give a reason whenever you downvote somebody is not following that...sorry to bother you.

Comment: It was a mistake that I used two different parameter names. Now I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

The following will do what you've described:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int* array = new int[10];

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
      array[i] = i;
      std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
   }

   delete [] array;

   return 0;
}
```

However in modern C++ the idomatic solution would be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v;

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
      v.push_back(i);
      std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The modern C++ way is to use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`

Comment: or `std::iota (std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);`

Answer (score 2):

You allocated memory for 10 integers for pInt but do not allocate any memory for array. Since array doesn't have any memory allocated it can not hold data. One solution is to just use your pInt variable. On that note where you have `*array[i] = i;` there is no need to dereference with * as having the brackets [] dereference the pointer. So you can replace that line with `pInt[i] = i;` then if you call `cout << *pInt;` you would get the first value in the array. You can cout each in a for loop like `cout << pInt[i];` One final thing that you may already know but just incase, whenever you use pointers and allocate memory by using `new` make sure you deallocate that memory when you are done to prevent memory leaks. For this you would do `delete[] pInt;`

Answer (score 1):

Allocate something in `array` otherwise how do you expect it to hold something.(unless you point it to some already allocated memory).

Or assign `array=pInt` and then you can use it to hold values. `array[i]=i`

An example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int *a;
    // int *b;
    // b= new int[10]; we can simply allocate it to 'a' directly
    // a = b;
    a = new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        a[i]=i;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        cout<<a[i];
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
```

}

> The pointer variable is nothing but address holder. So here `a` is not
>   holding anything significant before initializing. But once you
>   initialize it either by allocating `new` or assign it to something
>   similar it just doesn't point to nowhere. And once you do that you
>   have some chunk of memory which you can access by that pointer which
>   is what i did here. What if I didn't initialize and tried to use `a`.
>   it's Undefined behavior.

Don't use `bits/stdc++.h` [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). It might help you write small code but it should never be used in development or production level code.

Comment: reason for DV??

Comment: I don't understand the reason for DV...anybody?

Comment: Umm... Maybe [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)? Or memory leak? Owning raw pointer? Unnecessary variable?

Comment: @NickyC.: Check the answer now. Hope it helps.. and thanks for the inputs.

Comment: @NickyC.: Yes we can but look I just showed Op the get rid of the empty `a` case. Yes I would modify that.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a variable as

```
int *array=new int;
```

try this

```
int *array=new int;
int *pInt = new int[10];

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  *array = i;
  cout<<*array<<endl;
}
```

and if you want to display array from 0 to 9

try this

```
int *array=new int[10];
int *pInt = new int[10];

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  array[i] = i;
  cout<<array[i]<<endl;
}
```

for Adding of array
try this

```
int *array=new int;
int *pInt = new int[10];

for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
  pInt[i]=i;
  cout<<pInt[i]<<endl;
  *array=*array+pInt[i];
}
cout<<"Addition ="<<*array;
return 0;
```